# Use criteria.all on subobjects created by spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have an object containing an array of subobjects stored in mongo by spring-data-mongodb. Here is an example similar to my case :

```
{ 
    "_class" : "com.foo.bar.Customer", 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5050aef830041f24ff2bd16e"), 
    "name": "John Doe"
    "cart":
      [ 
       {
         productName: "test",
         "price": 9001
       },
       {
         "productName": "test2",
         "price": 1337
       }
      ],
     "discount":0
}
```

I'm doing an update query. Let's say I want to update the discount for all the customers with specific products in their cart. I'm doing this query

```
Update update = new Update();
update.set("discount", 10)
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
products.add(new Product("test", 9001);
products.add(new Product("test2", 1337);
WriteResult writeResult = mongoOps.updateMulti(query(where("cart").all(products)), update, Customer.class);
```

This does not work because Spring adds the _class property to each product used in the $all criterion, but spring didn't add the _class to the subobjects when I first saved the Customer.

Is there a way to make this work?

P.S : I'm using spring-data-mongodb 1.5.0. According to the doc, the subobjects should also have an _class attribute but they don't. Is this a known issue?

Comment: I also have the same issue when I do a ne() (not equal) on a list of subobjects.

Comment: The issue might also be that spring does not add the _class on the subobjects, but I have no idea what could cause that :(

Comment: There have been a few bugfix releases for 1.5 already, so you might wanna try the most recent 1.5.4 of if you can upgrade to 1.6 the latest 1.6.1. If that doesn't help feel free to create a ticket. Also, is the list of products using inheritance maybe?

Comment: Thank you, I tried to switch to 1.6 but it didn't fix the issue (with, in my opinion, is the fact that spring doesn't add the _class to the subobjects while the doc says it should. We decided to do the logic directly in Java, but I will try to create a very basic project to be sure that I have the same issue and I'll open a ticket.

Comment: After testing, the issue seems to be fixed in version 1.7.0.M1. It won't be useful in my case, but I think it answers this question. Thank you for your help Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in spring-data-mongodb. Spring should add the _class attribute to the subobjects or omit it when you query a subobject.

It seems to be fixed in the upcoming version of spring-data-mongodb (1.7.0.M1). In this version, the queries that compare subobjects does not add the _class attribute to the json sent to mongo.